# How to generate "x1" to "x200" pngs faster?

Tags: export, image

```
Table[
  Export[
    StringJoin["x", ToString[i], ".png"],
    Style[StringJoin["x", ToString[i]], RGBColor["#FF00FF"], 1024]
  ],
  {i, 1, 200}
]
```

How to make it faster?

Comment: Is there any reason to export pngs? why not pdfs? These are vector graphics and the format is quite fast when exporting (in my computer about 20 sec)...

Answer (score 7):

For example, you could export as svg and use a dedicated tool such as [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org) for rasterization. svg export is 20 times faster and ffmpeg is *really* fast for batch processing tasks (I used it quite often for creating videos from sequences of images).

```
ParallelDo[
 Export[
  StringJoin["x", IntegerString[i, 10, 4], ".svg"],
  Style[StringJoin["x", IntegerString[i, 10]], RGBColor["#FF00FF"], 
   1024]
  ], {i, 1, 200}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 2.34546

Then run

```
ffmpeg -width 1024 -y -i x%04d.svg x%04d.png
```

in the command line. This does the job within a few seconds. You will need a rather recent version of ffmpeg for it (3.4 or higher).

You can run the command line code also from within Mathematica with

```
ffmpegpath = "/opt/local/bin/";
filebasename = "x";
s = StringJoin["! ", FileNameJoin[{ffmpegpath, "ffmpeg"}], 
  " -width 1024 -y -i ", filebasename, "%04d.svg ", filebasename, 
  "%04d.png"]
Import[s, "Text"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> "! /opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -width 1024 -y -i x%04d.svg x%04d.png"
>
> 12.4168

Unfortunately, the svg rasterization is currently not as well parallelized as other task in ffmpeg...

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses [`ImageAssemble`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageAssemble.html).

Firstly, export individual element images containing `x`, `1`, `2`, and so on. Secondly, import those individual images and store it using an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html). Finally, assemble the images according to the specified text and export them.

```
path = "D:\\Desktop\\stack";
Export[path <> "\\elementImages\\x.png", Style[x, RGBColor["#FF00FF"], 1024]];
Table[Export[path <> "\\elementImages\\" <> ToString[i] <> ".png", 
   Style[ToString[i], RGBColor["#FF00FF"], 1024]], {i, 0, 9}];

xImage = Import[path <> "\\elementImages\\x.png"];
digitImage = 
  Table[i -> Import[path <> "\\elementImages\\" <> ToString[i] <> ".png"], {i, 0, 9}]
 // Association;

exportImageAssembled[i_] := 
  Export[path <> "\\x" <> ToString@i <> ".png", 
   ImageAssemble[{xImage, Sequence @@ (digitImage /@ IntegerDigits[i])}]];
```

---

For a fair comparison, I use the parallelized version of OP's code.

```
ParallelDo[exportImageAssembled[i], {i, 200}]; // AbsoluteTiming//First

ParallelDo[
    Export[StringJoin["D:\\Desktop\\stack\\OP\\x", ToString[i], ".png"], 
     Style[StringJoin["x", ToString[i]], RGBColor["#FF00FF"], 1024]], 
      {i, 1, 200}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 8.09534
>
> 89.6499

[`ImageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Iapproachestml) comparison of an exported image from both of these approaches.

```
a1 = ImageData[ Import@Export[ StringJoin[path <> "\\OP\\x", ToString[117], ".png"], 
     Style[StringJoin["x", ToString[117]], RGBColor["#FF00FF"], 1024]]];
a2 = ImageData[Import@exportImageAssembled[117]];
a1 == a2
```

> True