# Bold font is very rough in exported rasterized pdf

Tags: export, pdf-format, fonts

For example

```
test = DensityPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
   FrameLabel -> {"w", "E"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[13, Black]];
Export["test.pdf", Grid[{{test, test}}], "AllowRasterization"->True, ImageResolution -> 600]
```

The exported pdf (I intentionally used rasterization option, because I want rasterization) is like

[image]

However, if you set Bold LabelStyle

```
test = DensityPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
       FrameLabel -> {"w", "E"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold,13, Black]];
Export["test.pdf", Grid[{{test, test}}], "AllowRasterization"->True, ImageResolution -> 600]
```

the resulting font is rough

[image]

What is wrong? How to correctly setting Bold?

Comment: Oh my, `Export` is so broken. It is not as severe on my version 11.3 for macos but as long as I export a `Grid`, all settings for `ImageSize` and `ImageResolution` are effectively ignored. Export the graphic `test` alone seems to work fine.

Comment: What version of MMA do you use? It occurs to me that versions 10.0.x have such symptoms.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Yeah, I know it is only occured in Grid. And I am using 11.2 windows. And I have wasted several days on Export issue recently...

Comment: I don't observe this problem with *Mathematica* 11.3 on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 4):

What seems to work is doing the `Rasterization` by hand

```
img = Rasterize[
   GraphicsGrid[{{test, test}}],
   ImageResolution -> 600
   ];
Export["test.pdf", img]
```

[image]

Note that I use `GraphicsGrid` instead of `Grid`. Otherwise I would have gotten this mess:

[image]

**Edit**

Since I had to cope with a similar problem [yesterday](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172250/38178):

You may also try to export to svg and to use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org) (version 3.4.1 or higher) to do the rasterization. Apparently, the svg exporter treats `Grid` in the desired way.

```
test = DensityPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
   FrameLabel -> {"w", "E"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[13, Black, Bold]];
g = Grid[{{test, test}}];
file = Export["test.svg", g]
file = FileNameJoin[{If[
     StringLength[DirectoryName[file]] == 0,
     Directory[],
     DirectoryName[file]
     ],
    FileBaseName[file]}];
message = Import[
  StringJoin[{
    "! /opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -width 1024 -y -i ",
    file, ".svg ",
    file, ".png ", " 2>&1"
    }],
  "Text"
  ]
Import[file <> ".png"]
```

[image]

Note that you have to specify the image's resolution as an option of ffmpeg. I use `-width 1024` to specify the absolute number of pixels in x direction should be 1024; the number of pixels in y directions is computed from that and from the aspect ration of the bounding box in the svg.

A word of warning: In the past, I also encountered numerous problems with the svg exporter. So no guarantee for anything.

Comment: Hi, Henrik Schumacher. First an upvote : ) However, it has subtle issue. it brings back to my recent post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172192/4742. `GraphicsGrid` can not replace `Grid` in any case. Because, `Grid` can scale with content, while `GraphicsGrid` can not...

Comment: Try my example in my previous post like this `plot = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   ImageSize -> 100];
plots = GraphicsGrid[{{GraphicsGrid[Table[plot, {i, 2}, {j, 2}]], 
     Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> "yyy"]}}];
newplots = 
 GraphicsGrid[{{Show[plot, ImageSize -> 200, AspectRatio -> 2], 
    plots}}]`

Comment: Hi, Henrik Schumacher. Sorry for late comment. I just tried ffmpeg. I don't know if it is version issue. But my ffmpeg seems doesn't support `-width` option, it will complain "Unrecognized option 'width'". And if I simply run `ffmpeg -i test.svg test.png`, it will complain "Decoder (codec svg) not found for input stream". I can not find a solution. My ffmpeg version is 3.4, what is your version?

Comment: Oh, I just found a bug for svg exporter. Try `Export["R:\\test.svg", 
 ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]]`. The exported svg has many white lines

Comment: My ffmpeg version is 3.4.1. I run it on macOS High Sierra.

Comment: The white lines are a typical problem when exporting contourplots to vector graphics formats. Also happens with pdf. This has been addressed several times on this site; just have a look.